# Php Kcachegrind installation workflow 

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, kcachegrind

Mac environment (php v5.3.3).I need to analyze xdebug profiling logs.Reading around I understood that I should use Kcachegrind.I'm following a DevZone tutorial [Profiling PHP applications with Xdebug](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2899).I got stuck at two specific points:

```
If possible, use your system's packet manager to install the KCachegrind package.
KCachegrind uses GraphViz to draw the call graphs, so you must also install the 
GraphViz package if your packet manager does not automatically install it as a 
required dependecy.
```

and

```
As you can see, the path to the KDE libraries on your system is required. 
To configure the KCachegrind sources. If you are not sure where the KDE 
libraries are located on your system, use [..]
```

- What's a system's packet manager?
- What's KDE libraries and how do I get them installed?

I would also know if I should use Kcachegrind 0.4.6 or 0.10.1 (full Valgrind package) or there are other profiling tools that you want to suggest.

thanks

Luca

Comment: I dont think you have the packet manager in a mac, so you will have to manually instal it. xdebug website has very good documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac does have a packet manager ([MacPorts](http://www.macports.org)) , although you probably have to install that first. If you use that to install KCacheGrind, it will install the KDE libraries as dependencies.